# parse: retrieve object using pointer

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

In my app, an user can join multiple groups, so my User class has a column called groups, which is an array of group pointers.

E.g `[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Group","objectId":"123ABCxyz"},...]`.

What is the right way to convert / dereference these Group pointers to full Group objects?

Comment: Query the user and do query.include('groups'). Or from the list of objectids (query on Group) query.whereMatches('objectId', user.groups)

Answer (score 0):

It seems whereMatches is only for Android, I figured out that I can query the groups using containedIn.

```
(new Parse.Query('Group')).containedIn("objectId", groups.map((g)=>{return g.objectId}))
```